# Kotlin Chronometer Countdown wanting to stop to 0

Tags: kotlin

I made a basic app that has image 4 textviews and a button (quiz like). the textviews and the button are onclicklistener so when i click them something happens. The problem is i have a function that creates the window and one that inserts the questions. The clock starts ticking when i instert the question and i dont know how to stop it. Im using a chronometer for it

```
package com.example.quizviolence

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

class QuizQuestions : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    private var mCurrentPos: Int = 1
    private var mQuestionsList: ArrayList<Question>?= null
    private var mSelectedOptionPos: Int = 0
    private var mCorrectAns: Int=0
    private var mUserName: String?= null
    private var totaltime: Long= 0
    private lateinit var progress1: TextView
    private lateinit var progressBar1: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var question1: TextView
    private lateinit var textView1: TextView
    private lateinit var textView2: TextView
    private lateinit var textView3: TextView
    private lateinit var textView4: TextView
    private lateinit var image1: ImageView
    private lateinit var button1: Button
    private lateinit var view_timer: Chronometer
    var startTime: Long = 0
    var lifes:Int=3
    private lateinit var quizMusic:MediaPlayer
    private lateinit var rightAns:MediaPlayer
    private lateinit var wrongAns:MediaPlayer
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_questions)
        view_timer=findViewById(R.id.view_timer)
        mUserName=intent.getStringExtra(Consts.USER_NAME)
        progress1 = findViewById(R.id.tv_progress)
        progressBar1 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
        question1 = findViewById(R.id.tv_question)
        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.tv_option_one)
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.tv_option_two)
        textView3 = findViewById(R.id.tv_option_three)
        textView4 = findViewById(R.id.tv_option_four)
        image1 = findViewById(R.id.iv_image)
        button1= findViewById(R.id.btn_submit)
        mQuestionsList = Consts.getQuestions()
        setQuestion()
        button1.setOnClickListener(null)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun setQuestion() {
        quizMusic = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p_timer)
        quizMusic.start()
        button1.setOnClickListener(null)
        view_timer.isCountDown = true
        view_timer.base = elapsedRealtime() + 30000
        view_timer.start()
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val questionListNew= mQuestionsList!![mCurrentPos-1]
        textView1.setOnClickListener(this)
        textView2.setOnClickListener(this)
        textView3.setOnClickListener(this)
        textView4.setOnClickListener(this)
        defaultOptionView()
        if(mCurrentPos==mQuestionsList!!.size){
            button1.text="Finish"
        }else {
            button1.text = "Submit"
        }
        progressBar1.progress = mCurrentPos
        progress1.text = "$mCurrentPos" + "/" + progressBar1.max
        question1.text = questionListNew.question
        image1.setImageResource(questionListNew.image)
        textView1.text = questionListNew.optionOne
        textView2.text = questionListNew.optionTwo
        textView3.text = questionListNew.optionThree
        textView4.text = questionListNew.optionFour
    }
    private fun defaultOptionView(){
        val options=ArrayList<TextView>()
        options.add(0,textView1)
        options.add(1,textView2)
        options.add(2,textView3)
        options.add(3,textView4)

        for (option in options){
            option.setTextColor(0xFF7A8089.toInt())
            option.typeface= Typeface.DEFAULT
            option.background=ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.default_option_boarder_bg)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            when (p0?.id) {
                textView1.id -> {
                    button1.setOnClickListener(this)
                    selectedOptionView(textView1, 1)
                }
                textView2.id -> {
                    button1.setOnClickListener(this)
                    selectedOptionView(textView2, 2)
                }
                textView3.id -> {
                    button1.setOnClickListener(this)
                    selectedOptionView(textView3, 3)
                }
                textView4.id -> {
                    button1.setOnClickListener(this)
                    selectedOptionView(textView4, 4)
                }
                button1.id -> {
                    textView1.setOnClickListener(null)
                    textView2.setOnClickListener(null)
                    textView3.setOnClickListener(null)
                    textView4.setOnClickListener(null)
                    if (mSelectedOptionPos == 0) {
                                mCurrentPos++
                                when {
                                    mCurrentPos <= mQuestionsList!!.size -> {
                                        setQuestion()
                                    }
                                    else -> {
                                        val intent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)
                                        intent.putExtra(Consts.USER_NAME, mUserName)
                                        intent.putExtra(Consts.TIMER_LEFT, totaltime)
                                        intent.putExtra(Consts.CORRECT_ANSWERS, mCorrectAns)
                                        intent.putExtra(Consts.TOTAL_QUESTIONS, mQuestionsList!!.size)
                                        startActivity(intent)
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (button1.text == "Submit") {
                                    val question = mQuestionsList?.get(mCurrentPos - 1)
                                    if (question!!.correctAns != mSelectedOptionPos) {
                                        ansView(mSelectedOptionPos, R.drawable.wrong_option_boarder_bg)
                                        view_timer.stop()
                                        quizMusic.stop()
                                        wrongAns = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p_wrong)
                                        wrongAns.start()
                                        lifes -= 1
                                        if (lifes == 0) {
                                            val life_image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.life1)
                                            life_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                                            val intent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)
                                            intent.putExtra(Consts.USER_NAME, mUserName)
                                            intent.putExtra(Consts.TIMER_LEFT, totaltime)
                                            intent.putExtra(Consts.CORRECT_ANSWERS, mCorrectAns)
                                            intent.putExtra(Consts.TOTAL_QUESTIONS, mQuestionsList!!.size)
                                            startActivity(intent)
                                        }
                                        if (lifes == 2) {
                                            val life_image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.life3)
                                            life_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                                        }
                                        if (lifes == 1) {
                                            val life_image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.life2)
                                            life_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                view_timer.stop()
                                quizMusic.stop()
                                rightAns = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p_right)
                                rightAns.start()
                                mCorrectAns++
                                totaltime += System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
                                if (mCorrectAns % 5 == 0) {
                                    lifes += 1
                                    if (lifes == 2) {
                                        val life_image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.life2)
                                        life_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_full)
                                    }
                                    if (lifes == 3) {
                                        val life_image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.life3)
                                        life_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_full)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ansView(question.correctAns, R.drawable.correct_option_boarder_bg)
                        }

                        if (mCurrentPos == mQuestionsList!!.size) {
                            button1.text = "Finish"
                        } else {
                            button1.text = "Next Question"
                        }
                        mSelectedOptionPos = 0
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    private fun ansView(answer:Int,drawableView: Int){
        when(answer){
            1 ->{
                textView1.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,drawableView)
            }
            2 ->{
                textView2.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,drawableView)
            }
            3 ->{
                textView3.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,drawableView)
            }
            4 ->{
                textView4.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,drawableView)
            }
        }

    }
    private fun selectedOptionView(tv: TextView,selectedOptionNumber:Int)  {
        defaultOptionView()
        mSelectedOptionPos= selectedOptionNumber
        tv.setTextColor(0xFF363A43.toInt())
        tv.setTypeface(tv.typeface,Typeface.BOLD)
        tv.background=ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.selected_option_boarder_bg)
    }
```

I tried using while and when in the question function but it doesnt seem to work. I just want when timer hits 0 deactivate the onclick textviews and change the button from submit to change question but i havent figured out how to actually manage to stop the clock when timer hits 0

Comment: Edit your question to show only the relevant code based on your question. Where is your implementation of the timer?